# Different orientation options in 2 different projects?

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation

This is from one of my projects:

[image]

And this is from a different project:
[image]

Why does the second one have the separate iPhone and iPad buttons but not the first? I'd like the first to have the two buttons as well because I need different orientations for that project. How?

Comment: Did you start both projects in the same version of Xcode?

Comment: becoz first one is below xcode 6.0 and it doesn't support 8.0, but second one do ,that's why you getting iphone/ipad option, try to set correct deployment target in first project then you will get iphone/ipad option. @pizzafilms

Comment: Doubtful. But I looked at the Info.plist files for each and they look nearly identical in any field that looks even remotely applicable.

Comment: have u noticed 8.0 is bit shadow in first project

Comment: Thanks @sanjeet, but I tried setting deployment target to 7.0 and 6.1 and the separate buttons still don't show up.